# Prevent css inheriting

Tags: css

I am creating a banner that has a form in it to go on various different websites. However, when it goes on other websites it inherits the style from the first one. So sometimes it looks messed up. Is there a way to make it so that the css won't inherit?

Comment: You could always use inline styles for it.

Comment: Yeah i used inline style for most of it but i cant think of every scenario and overwrite every style.

Answer (score 2):

Insert it into the sites using an iframe.  Other than that it may be tough.  You could try explicitly setting every style using very specific selectors.  Then it would be hard to override them.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to have to reset all styles in a parent container for your form and then place your form in that container.

Also use a unique name for your classes such as `.myform-banner-mysitename` or something. Even then, it sounds like you're designing your way to a world of pain.